# Django form input weird behavior

Tags: html, django

I am trying to generate a django form and it seems pretty straightforward.

```
                       <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="ad-interest">
                                Ad Interest
                            </label>
                                {{ form.ad_interest }}
                        </div>
```

It generated this:

[image: ad-interest]

However When I try wrapping some `HTML` around the `input` the closing `>` of the `input` tag is also generated on the page.

Updated input tag:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="ad-interest">
        Ad Interest
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" id="ad-interest" value="{{ form.ad_interest }}" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Generates this:

[image: new ad-interest]

I dont understand why the "extra" stuff is showing up on the form. The functionality isnt affected though

Answer (score 1):

I bet your form field `ad_interest` is a `CharField`, so by doing `{{ form.ad_interest }}`, django is already using the default widget for `CharField`, that's why without doing anything in your first case you've already got a `<input .....>` html.

However, if you wrap the default widget into another layer of `<input...>`, the html could obviously show as above. Essicially you were having following html, which is invalid:

```
<input type="text" class="..." value="<input...>" >
```

You would see the default widget html by using barely `{{ form.ad_interest }}` and also, your field renders by itself correctly, right? :)

See django doc [widget for `TextInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#textinput).

Comment: I know using `form.fieldname` generates the input box, your answers explain how to generate the input field but not how to wrap it in `HTML` or explain why the `>` is shown on the page

Comment: I don't think you understand what's going on. The input box you see in your first case is ALREADY html. How do you think a text box would appear without html code?

Comment: That is common knowledge. Still does not explain how to stylize a django input field without the error I get

Comment: The `>` shows up simply because your html is messed up. If you don't have valid html, your browser would treat all characters in your web page as literal strings.

Comment: I get 0 errors on the IDE and that is the only piece of code I have, disregarding `extend` blocks

Comment: To stylize the django field, you either use `attr` to customize the widget: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs, or you write your own widget.

Comment: Your IDE doesn't show error because IDE doesn't see what's the html after your widget is rendered in the browser would look like. Your code doesn't generate error until django renders `{{ form.ad_interest }}` to html.